# "Value toSeq is not a member of Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, either

I've got an `RDD` of text files which I want to parse. I achieve this by mapping a function over them which returns `Either[String, Book]` where `Book` is the structured type resulting from parsing, or `String` is the text which could not be parsed. The result of this is an `RDD[Either[String, Book]]`. I would like to have an `RDD[String]` and an `RDD[Book]`, because the former should be logged and discarded, and the latter should be processed more.

My splitter is:

```
implicit class EitherRDDOps[L, R](rdd: RDD[Either[L, R]]) {
    def split(): (RDD[L], RDD[R]) = {
        // toSeq on Either provides empty Seq for Right and one-element Seq for Left
        val left: RDD[L] = rdd.flatMap(_.swap.toSeq)
        val right: RDD[R] = rdd.flatMap(_.toSeq)
        (left, right)
    }
}
```

The splitter is called as `input.map(parseBook).cache.split`, where `input` is an `RDD[String]` and `parseBook` is a `(String) => Either[String, Book]`.

I get the following compilation errors:

```
value toSeq is not a member of Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either
       val left: RDD[L] = rdd.flatMap(_.swap.toSeq)
                                     ^

value toSeq is not a member of Either[L,R]
       val right: RDD[R] = rdd.flatMap(_.toSeq)
                                 ^

type mismatch;
  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Nothing]
  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[L]
 Note: Nothing <: L, but class RDD is invariant in type T.
 You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
       (left, right)
        ^

  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Nothing]
  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[R]
 Note: Nothing <: R, but class RDD is invariant in type T.
 You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
       (left, right)
              ^
```

But [the documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html) clearly lists a `toSeq` method on `Either`. Any idea? Should I be going about this differently?

Comment: The doc says that `toSeq` returns one-element for `Right` and zero elements for `Left`. But that doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: I don't use apache-spark so not too familiar with the constructs being used here but in my experience, this Product With Serializable stuff occurs when the type needs to be specified explicitly. See if you're able to do that (it will be a bit more verbose but could solve the issue)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin oops, typo in a comment. Thanks. The code was the right way around, though.

Comment: @JordanCutler Um. I added type specifiers to `left` and `right` but that didn't make a difference. Did you mean somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. Add the type to the result of calling swap. `rdd.flatMap(left => val something: TypePlaceholder = left.swap; left.toSeq)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if you are using a slightly older version of Scala, maybe 2.11.x or something like that. The `Either` has been updated recently, older versions might have no `toSeq`: [link to 2.11.8 documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.util.Either).

Try this instead:

```
val left = rdd.filter(_.isRight).map(_.right.get)
val right = rdd.filter(_.isLeft).map(_.left.get)
```

Comment: Almost. Now the error is `No ClassTag available for L` (and the same for `R`). In both cases it's pointing at the open-paren after `map`.

Comment: @DavidHeyman Why not just add `EitherRDDOps[L: ClassTag, R: ClassTag]`? If it requires `ClassTag`, it should already be available for `Either[L, R]` anyway. In your case, it's `String` and `Book`: should be no problem to provide class tag for that at the use-site.

Comment: Because I'm new to Scala and didn't previously know what ClassTags are or how to provide them or what the syntax you've put there means. I'm now shaky on some of it but have looked up enough to get this to compile.

Comment: @DavidHeyman `ClassTag`s are essentially runtime representations of a class that allow to do low-level stuff like array allocations (e.g., the `ClassTag` knows the `sizeof` that is required by a class instance). The `foo[A : Typeclass](b: C)`-syntax is shortcut for `foo[A](b: C)(implicit tc: Typeclass[A])`, in this case with `Typeclass[X] = ClassTag[X]`.

Comment: Thanks. Is that provided automatically/implicitly at the use site or do I need to provide it somehow? Can't seem to find anything saying how to provide it, or saying that I don't need to do so.

Comment: @DavidHeyman Ah, yes, important point! The `ClassTag` are inserted by the compiler automatically, but only for concrete types, for which you know what the concrete class is. It does not work for generics, as in your example: the compiler could not find `ClassTag` for `L` and `R`, because it knows nothing about `L` and `R`. This is why you had to require the `ClassTag`s as implicit arguments. Now these implicit arguments can be inserted at the call site with concrete classes `String` and `Book`, and the compiler will generate the tags automatically.

Comment: Rephrase: Do I need to explicitly say `[String, Book]` somewhere near the call to `split` (and if so where), or will the fact that the types are concrete and known statically at the point where it is called be sufficient?

Comment: @DavidHeyman You probably won't need to add `[String, Book]` when calling `split`. The `ClassTag`s will be inserted automatically as soon as the types are known at the call-site. The types will most probably be known because of type inference. All you have to do is to add `: ClassTag` in the declaration site, everything else is done automatically. Adding `: ClassTag` is not done automatically though, because it's a non-trivial tradeoff: if you add `: ClassTag`, you will have to make sure that it propagates through the entire codebase everywhere it is needed. It's not always easy to guarantee.

Comment: @DavidHeyman ...however, when working with Spark, you can usually attach `: ClassTag` where you need it, because the entire infrastructure of Spark relies on it anyway. Whether you want to require `ClassTag`s when you are designing your own independent library is a much more difficult design decision.